# Avoiding type warning for lists of sortable elements

Tags: python, types, type-hinting, python-dataclasses

I've got a list of elements of a dataclass X (marked `order=True`) and pass them to `max()`.  I get a type checking warning in my IDE: `Expected type 'Iterable' (matched generic type 'Iterable[SupportsLessThanT]'), got 'List[X]' instead`.  How can I avoid this error?  What do I have to declare to make the warning disappear?  (I don't want to suppress it of course.)

I thought because the class X is marked as `order=True` it would be obviously sortable, so that passing it to `max()` should be no problem.  But apparently this isn't known to the type system.

```
@dataclass(frozen=True, order=True)
class X:
    value: int

def f(xs: List[X]) -> None:
    q = max(xs)  # here's the above mentioned type checking warning
```

I tried inheriting various things in the class X but nothing helped.

Is there a supposed way to deal with this or do I have to ignore the warning?

Comment: As the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.List) says `List` is "Useful for annotating return types. To annotate arguments it is preferred to use an abstract collection type such as `Sequence` or `Iterable`."

Comment: You could ignore it if you know your code is going to run flawlessly. However, for good typing, you should specify that your parameter can be used as a parameter of `max`. Check the stubs: `def max(__iterable: Iterable[SupportsLessThanT], *, key: None = ...) -> SupportsLessThanT: ...` That means that the elements in your list must have the `__lt__` method. If `X` was an arbitrary class that doesn't implement that method, it would cause exceptions when passed in a list to `f()`. The solution is to just use the types that the IDE expects, unless that's wrong, and in that case, so is your code.

Comment: @martineau Yes, but I actually _have_ a `List[X]` as parameter so I should be able to declare it, regardless of the implementation of the function (specifically whether it uses `max()` or not).  Other parts of the function use the fact that the parameter is a list (use `len(xs)`, etc.).

Comment: @Shinratensei The spec means that the type of x needs to match the `SupportsLessThanT` criterion.  I don't know how to match that, and that's my question.  The `dataclass` with the marker `order=True` means exactly this: the `__lt__()` method is defined and stable for a set of instances.

Comment: It's quite possible, then, that the IDE simply doesn't have support for the `order` parameter of the dataclass. Have you searched for any issues on that?

Comment: Alfe: Please reread my comment. I know you have `List[X]` as the type of a parameter, which the documentation implies it is **not** designed for (and suggests two alternatives).

Comment: @martineau You are right, accepting `List` only is rather strict; using `Sequence` is better in terms of general programming.  My functions aren't really general but very specific for my special task.  Anyway, I replaced the `List` by `Sequence` but of course that didn't solve the issue of this question.

Comment: "I get a type checking warning in my IDE" Which IDE are you using? The current MyPy accepts this without a problem.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Interesting.  I'm using IntelliJ IDEA with the Python Community Edition plugin from JetBrains.

Comment: Ah, yes, that matches my experience with PyCharm. The builtin type checker is usually a bit behind the current status quo of the ecosystem.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi So you are saying this is a bug^H^H^Hmissing feature in the underlying PyCharm implementation and your proposal would be to wait until it is fixed?

Comment: You can also write a ticket for the Intellij community to alert them on this issue. Don't expect it to be resolved quickly though, their backlog is massive. The best course of action is probably to take Inellij's opinion as suggestion, and mypy's as the actual source of truth.

Comment: What did tou try to make `X` inherit from? Did you try making it inherit from `SupportsLessThanT`, for instance?

Comment: Yes, I tried inheriting anything I came up with, of course including `SupportsLessThenT` (also without `T`) and IIRC that wasn't something I could actually import from somewhere (the IDE and the execution also weren't agreeing on that, meaning that the IDE auto-inserted an import [from some strange library though which didn't seem right anyway] which the execution from command line then didn't find).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is fine as is. This is purely an issue of the type checker, in this case PyCharm/Intellij. Other type checkers such as MyPy correctly understand that the `dataclass` supports ordering.

```py
# so.py
from typing import List
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass(frozen=True, order=True)
class X:
    value: int

def f(xs: List[X]) -> None:
    q = max(xs)
```

```sh
python -m mypy so.py --strict
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

Since the builtin PyCharm/Intellij type checker is rarely up to date, it can be worthwhile not to treat it as authoritative. Rely on a second type checker and ignore the issue until the builtin type checker is updated.

If you want to help the builtin type checker, you can manually define a `Protocol` to express "this type is orderable". Inheriting the `dataclass` from this `Protocol` marks it as orderable.

```py
from typing import List, Protocol
from dataclasses import dataclass

class Orderable(Protocol):
    def __lt__(self, other) -> bool:
        ...
    def __gt__(self, other) -> bool:
        ...
    # add more comparison methods as desired

@dataclass(frozen=True, order=True)
class X(Orderable):
    value: int

def f(xs: List[X]) -> None:
    q = max(xs)  # fine for PyCharm/Intellij
```

Answer (score 1):

Postponed evaluation of annotations (https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html#pep-563-postponed-evaluation-of-annotations) can help here.

```
from __future__ import annotations

from typing import Sequence

from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass(frozen=True, order=True)
class X:
    value: int


def f(xs: Sequence[X: X]) -> None:
    q = max(xs)  # no warning here anymore
```

This works both in IDE and when launched from command line.